# MIPS assembly a simple for loop (2)

Tags: loops, assembly, mips

This is my 1st effort towards learning looping in MIPS.

```
.data
    spc: .asciiz ", "

.globl main

main:
    li $t0, 0

loop:
    bgt     $t0, 14, exit # branch if($t0 > 14) 
    addi    $t0, $t0, 1 # $t0++ for loop increment

    # print a comma
    la  $a0, spc # copy spc to $a0 for printing
    li  $v0, 4 # syscall value for strings
    syscall

    # repeat loop
    j   loop

exit:
    li  $v0, 10 # syscall value for program termination
    syscall
```

Output:

```
 -- program is finished running (dropped off bottom) --
```

This program is supposed to print 15 commas in the I/O console. That isn't taking place.

What could be the issue?

Ref: [MIPS assembly for a simple for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9155336/mips-assembly-for-a-simple-for-loop)

Comment: `# copy spc to $a0`  No, that comment is wrong.  `la` sets `$a0` = the *address* of the label.  It doesn't *copy* `spc` from anywhere; it has to materialize the static address in the register from immediate data.  (Like `lui` / `ori`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assembled all your code into the `.data` section; you never switched back to `.text`.

If you're using MARS, the GUI shows no asm instructions in the disassembly (after assembling).  This is why.

Apparently instead of faulting on `main` being in a non-executable page, MARS simply decides that the program "dropped off the bottom" as soon as you start it.

Comment: what about the other program shown in the linked page?

Comment: @user366312: what about it?  Adding `.text` before `main:` makes your code work correctly; I don't see any other parts of the question that need answering.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9155336/mips-assembly-for-a-simple-for-loop    this program doesn't have `.text`

Comment: @user366312: Yes, it does. It never switches to the `.data` segment, so it is *all* in the `.text` segment.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, oh, got it.